# De-serializing non existing implementation of interface

Tags: java, serialization, kotlin, jvm, deserialization

Imagine two separate projects that have common interfaces - for example both contains `interface CommonA`. Now, running `Program#1` contains `class Project1Class : CommonA`, but second does not. Is it possible to somehow serialize, transfer (ie. through network) and then in `Program#2` de-serialize instance of `Project1Class` although it does not know implementation of it?

My problem is following:

`Program#2` provides interfaces for heavy task computation - you implement interface which says how it should be computed (everything is immutable). I would like to have second `Program#1` (completely separated from `#2`) in which are these interfaces implemented and during runtime sent to `Program#2` which afterward de-serialize these classes, uses them for computation and then returns computed data.

For example - `Program#2` does not know how to perform `+` operation but provides interface `interface NumberMagic` with method `int doStuff(int a, int b)`. In `Program#1` this interface is implemented to something like `class Add : NumberMagic { override int doStuff(int a, int b) { return a + b; } }`. But machine which is powering `Program#1` is not powerful enough to do such a job so it needs to be sent to `Program#2`.

JVM world (more specifically Kotlin). - Is there a way how to do it? Maybe even with sending "source code" of `Add` class and then compiling it on machine running `Program#2`?

Comment: I you want 'Program#2' to access features / behavior in `Program#1`, passing a serialized Java object from #1 to #2 will not do that.   Java serialization requires the class that serialized the object to be available during deserialization.    Even if you substitute another class in Program#2 (e.g. via setting serialVersionUID and such), Program#2 will deserialize into *that* class and will have the methods from that class.

Comment: The most common way to access the code of one process from another is to use a remote API protocol such as RMI, gRPC, and the like.